# Extract HTML-Content from URL of Site that probably uses Cookies via Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I recently wanted to extract data from a website that seems to use cookies to grant me access. I do not know very much about those procedures but appearently this inteferes with my method of getting the html content of the website via Python and its requests module.

The code I am running to extract the information contains the following lines:

```
import responses
#...
response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
content = requests.text
```

Where the website i am referring to is http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/icp.jsp?arnumber=6675630&tag=1 and proxies is a valid dict of my proxy servers (I tested those settings on websites that seemed to work fine). However, instead of the content of the article on this site I receive the html-content of the page that you get when you do not accept cookies in your browser.

As I am not really aware of what website is really doing and lack real Web-Developement experience I could not find a solution so far, even if a similar question might have been asked before. Is there any solution to access the content of this website via Python?

Answer (score 0):

```
startr = requests.get('https://viennaairport.com/login/')

secondr = requests.post('http://xxx/', cookies=startr.cookies)
```

Comment: Uhm, I do not quite understand. I dont want to login, I just want to get the content of the website. I guess in my case the startresponse would be what I currently receive (the variable "response"). But where to send those cookies? And more relevant - where to get the sites content afterwards?